# open the first section when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<li class="page_item ">
    <a href="javascript:">A</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item"><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li class="page_item"><a href="">2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item ">
    <a href="">B</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item"><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li class="page_item"><a href="">2</a></li>
        <li class="page_item"><a href="">3</a></li>
        <li class="page_item"><a href="">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item ">
    <a href="">C</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item"><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li class="page_item"><a href="">2</a></li>
        <li class="page_item"><a href="">3</a></li>
        <li class="page_item"><a href="">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

JS:

```
$('.page_item').click(function() {
    var that = this;
    $('.page_item').each(function() {
        if (that == this) return true; //continue
        $('.children:not(:hidden)', this).slideToggle();
    });
    $('ul.children', this).slideToggle();
});
```

Online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kHLuR/1/

How can I make the first section `li` opened by default?

Comment: Would be better to do it with CSS in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Variant #1** Pure CSS solution:

```
.page_item:first-child .children {
    display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/kHLuR/7/

Note: `:first-child` works in IE8+. If you need to support older version you can give another class to your first li, e.g: `<li class="page_item page_item-first">` http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/kHLuR/9/

**Variant #2.** Trigger click event on the first `.page_item`:

```
$('.page_item').click(function () {
    // ...
})
.filter(':first').click();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/kHLuR/8/

Comment: Many Thanks! 2 options. `.filter` or `trigger` which one is better

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to simulate a click event when the page is loaded: <kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kHLuR/5/)**</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').eq(0).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Does `eq(0)` the first `a`? I've changed 0 to 1, it still opens the first li? thanks

Comment: `eq` function (zero based) return the JQuery object in relation with the selector. In my example, `eq(0)` return the first link <a> element, `eq(1)` the second. If you want open by default the second section, you need to simulate a click on the fourth <a> then use `eq(3)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's .ready() to execute code immediately after the page loads.
Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/ready/